# Problem with connection string using

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, connection-string

I have an ASP.NET project which gives me the [following](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/3045472/images/Capture.PNG) exception if I try to run it

[image]

Where should I "call" it before I can use it ?

---

There is no global.asax in my solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it should be called  [only once](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.cloudstorageaccount.setconfigurationsettingpublisher%28v=MSDN.10%29.aspx), you should put it in your global.asax Application_Start function IMO

Answer (score 1):

This method is from Class [**CloudStorageAccount**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.cloudstorageaccount.aspx) that provides methods for managing account information for storage services.

`SetConfigurationSettingPublisher` Method should be called `once` to set up the environment.

Try calling it `in Global.asax` in  `Application_Start` Method.

This link at MSDN might help

- [**CloudStorageAccount.SetConfigurationSettingPublisher
  Method**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.cloudstorageaccount.setconfigurationsettingpublisher.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I had set a web-role as the startup project, and that made the "onstart" funcition not run when it was supposed to, thus not setting my connection.